# how to convert a blob into video?

Tags: php

i want to change an blob into video format. Before this i try to convert the blob into image by the following code.

```
<?php
$data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
       . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
       . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
       . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
$data = base64_decode($data);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
}
?>
```

is there any way to convert a blob into video...??

Comment: that depends on what the 'blob' contains

Comment: blob contains the video

Comment: is there a function like imagecreatefromstring()

Comment: don't need one, just set the right headers

Comment: it will not work...string should be first converted in video.

Comment: it will work, show the code you tried.

Comment: If your "blob" comes from a file then you don't need PHP. Just link (or redirect) to the video file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just output the `$data` with the right headers (`header('Content-Type: video/xxx')`, where `xxx` is the format of the stored video).

Edit: Same for the image, `imagepng()` just creates the same string again as it was in `$data`, you dont need that useless step.

Comment: same thing can be done with the image also..but it will not working for image then how it will work for a video

Comment: If it is not working you are doing something wrong, just set the right header and then `echo $data;`.

Comment: yeah its working.. thnx :)

Comment: And then what? how can I save that created video as a file in a specific directory?